# jQuery + node.js express POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I'm trying to send a post request to a node server.
This is my client-side code:

```
function send(userid,message){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/chat/messages?id="+userid+'&message='+message
    })
    clear();
}
```

This is my server side code:

```
  app.post('/chat/messages',function (req,res){
    var query = url.parse(req.url,true).query
    insertMessage(query.id,query.message)
  })
```

This works, however I'm not sure getting data in the query string using post is the right way to go.

I tried adding a data field in `$ajax` parameter:

```
function send(userid,message){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/chat/messages"
        data : {'id' : userid, 'message' : message}
    })
    clear();
}
```

And using `bodyParser()` in the server end to parse the body contents:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.post('/chat/messages',function (req,res){
    console.log(req.body)
})
```

but when I log the response, the `body{ }` object is always empty.
Why is that? 
Is a `<form>` tag necessary for POST requests?

I tried editing my ajax request to use `json` as the dataType and stringifying the data, but the `req.body` is still empty.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/chat/messages",
    data : JSON.stringify({'id' : userid, 'message' : message}),
    dataType: 'json',
})
```

Comment: you aren't sending json, so... that's the wrong bodyparser. If you wanted to send json, you would need to stringify the object you are sending to the data parameter. Would also help to set the contentType in that case.

Comment: but even with `bodyParser.raw()`, the request body remains empty.

Comment: why is my question being downvoted? can someone tell me whats wrong with it?

Comment: urlencoded is what you want.

Comment: contentType, not dataType. dataType is for what you expect the server to return.

Comment: yes! urlencoded works! Thanks Kevin B!

Comment: urlencoded works because POST fields are sent as a urlencoded string in the body, much like the querystring sent in the url of a GET request.

Comment: Regarding why your question is getting downvoted, I've experienced that here on stackoverflow too, despite feeling I've asked reasonable questions. Unfortunately, users are not required to leave feedback when they downvote, which would be really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you post data to a server, the data is usually urlencoded and added to the body of the request. In your example, it would look like this:

```
id=<userid>&message=<message>
```

Therefore, the bodyparser you need to be able to parse that is `bodyparser.urlencoded()`

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
```

Note that it isn't always urlencoded, it all depends on what you are using to send the post. AngularJS for example defaults to sending it as json instead. The good news is you could simply add both bodyparsers and your route won't need to know which method was used since in both cases the data would end up on req.body with key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the express documentation. http://expressjs.com/api.html#req

```
// For regular html form data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
app.post('/chat/messages',function (req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.query.id);
    console.log(req.query.messages);
})
```

You can also do req.params

```
app.post('/chat/messages/:id',function (req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.query);
    console.log(req.params.id)
})
```